# Python3 custom decode

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i migrate my code from python2 to python3.My code is not producing desired result instead it generate error: code snippet and error log as shown below.

```
import os
import sys
import base64
def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)
    print(enc)
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        print(key_c)
        dec_c = chr((256 + ord(enc[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256)
        print(dec_c)
        dec.append(dec_c)
    return "".join(dec)

contents = "p6KisaignLOinZqgmqKin6OT0uTZ0tSTlaKmpI+klJ+loI"
decodedLicense = decode('crab',contents)
```

Error Log:

```
File "s.py", line 16, in decode
    dec_c = chr((256 + ord(enc[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Comment: use `print()` and `print(type())` to check value in `enc[i]` and `key_c` before you use it in `ord()`

Comment: Oh dear, why are you implementing crypto yourself?!? For safety's sake, use a library!

Comment: Python 2 treads decoded text as string but Python 3 treads it as bytes/numbers - check `print(enc[i], type(enc[i]))`

Comment: I get a different error (using Python 3.6.3) from the line `enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)` -> `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding` (in `File "C:\Python3\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode`). This sounds like the value you have for `contents` is invalid.

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but there's comments in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/base64.py#l120) of the `urlsafe_b64decode()` function that describe what condition might cause the `binascii.Error` padding exception.

Comment: Thank you all who responded to this question

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if the final result is correct since you didn't indicate what the desired or expected output was in your question, which makes that very difficult to determine.

Anyhow, as I said in a comment, initially I was getting a different error complaining about the the length of `contents` having `Incorrect padding`, so the first thing I did was add something to fix that. Afterwards. I started getting the `TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found` exception you *did* mention in your question.

That was fixed by just using the bytes that `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()` returned direct and not trying to take their `ord()`.

Here's code with these changes made that at least runs...:

```
import os
import sys
import base64

def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc).decode('latin1')
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec_c = chr((256 + enc[i] - ord(key_c)) % 256)  # ord(enc[i]) -> enc[i]
        dec.append(dec_c)

    return "".join(dec)

contents = "p6KisaignLOinZqgmqKin6OT0uTZ0tSTlaKmpI+klJ+loI"  # 46 chars

# Pad contents so its length is a multiple of 3 and it's valid Base64 data.
contents = contents + {0: '', 1: '==', 2: '='}[len(contents) % 3]

decodedLicense = decode('crab', contents)
print(decodedLicense)  # -> D0AOE.;Q?+9>70A=@!q?v`s120EB,23=B.
```